# How to find the login information necesary for vsftpd on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I installed a FTP vsftpd on my Ubuntu box and after toying with it I can login from the same machine using 'ftp localhost'.

Now I'm trying to login from another virtual machine; where do I find the information necessary to connect to it?

Also, I have anonymous login enabled but it still asks me for a user name and password; what do I type in there to login as anonymous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[try this out i think it will help set login as anonymous](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/12/02/set-up-an-anonymous-ftp-server-with-vsftpd-in-less-than-a-minute/)

Answer (score 0):

There is an explanation of how to configure vsftpd [in the Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/ftp-server.html).

To connect to it, use the IP address or (if avahi is installed on both machines and both are on the same LAN) add ".local" to the hostname of the FTP-server machine and use that to connect to the FTP server.

And you can login using the username "anonymous".